# Proof that a sequence of random variables have finite expectation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_n$ be iid non-negatives random variables. Prove that $\mathbb{E}[X_1] < \infty$ iff $P(X_n \ge n\text{ i.o.}) = 0$

I thought I would start like this for one direction

$\infty > \mathbb{E}[X_1] \ge \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty P( X_n > n)$ then the first Borel Cantelli Theorem states that

$$P(X_n \ge n\text{ i.o.}) = 0$$

but how would I go forward with the other direction ?

Comment: Have you looked at the second B-C theorem? (:

Answer (score 1):

You can use Borel's Zero-One Law [(prop. 2.2 here)](http://www.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring07/sta205/lec/indep.pdf), using $$\mathbb{E} X_1 \leqslant \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}\{X_1 > n\} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}\{X_n > n\}$$ with $A_n\stackrel{\rm{}def}{=}\{X_n > n\}$.

Comment: You've assumed that $X_i$ are discrete here.

Comment: Yes, indeed (in the first equality).

Comment: What I meant was that the question doesn't say that $X$ is discrete.  You should really have $\mathbb EX_1 \geq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb P\{X_n>n\} \geq \mathbb EX_1 - 1$ to address this.

Comment: That's what I gathered from your comment -- but I wasn't sure about  how to fix it, to be honest.

Comment: The modification (1 character!) should take care of this.

Comment: How can you conclude that $\mathbb{E}[X_1] < \infty$ from $P(X_n \ge n\text{ i.o.}) = 0$ ?

Comment: By contrapositive of Prop. 2.2, you have $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{P} A_n < +\infty$.

Comment: thanks, got it, maybe it was too obvious